# How to loop a Draggable slider in React

Tags: reactjs, sass, slider, carousel, draggable

I have a draggable horizontal slider in my current project and I would like to setting up it also to loop continuously. By loop continuously I mean it should respond to the process of showing images one after another when dragging? Right now, I do have only 3 images in my slider and when I drag slider to the left, slider with its 3rd image and a blank white space starts showing just after. Here at this point I want images to get start again continuously from the very beginning i.e. from the 1st image with aim to cover the white blank space.

Apart, one error I'm getting with my existing code is that when I start to drag slider to right side, suddenly a scroll comes up on browser and keep going in never ending state. By never ending state, I mean it still remain on screen when I drag all my 3 images fully in right direction.

So these are the two things I want to apply and want to resolve in my current project. I'm sharing my code below.

**src > Routes > Home > Components > Carousel > Components > SliderDataItems > index.js**

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { Draggable } from "gsap/Draggable";
import { ZoomInOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons'
import { Images } from '../../../../../../Shared/Assets';
import ImagesIcon from '../../../../../../Components/Cells/ImagesIcon'
gsap.registerPlugin(Draggable);

const pictures = [
  {
    img: Images.xgallery1,
    icon: <ZoomInOutlined />
  },
  {
    img: Images.xgallery2,
    icon: <ZoomInOutlined />
  },
  {
    img: Images.xgallery4,
    icon: <ZoomInOutlined />
  },
];

const Slide = ({ img, icon }) => {
  return (
    <div className="slide">
      <div className="image">
        <ImagesIcon src={img} />
        <div className="icon">
          {icon}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export const Slider = () => {
  const sliderRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    Draggable.create(sliderRef.current, {
      type: "x"

    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="slider" ref={sliderRef}>
      {pictures.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <Slide key={index} img={item.img} icon={item.icon} />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Slider;
```

**src > Routes > Home > Components > Carousel > style.scss**

```
.slider {
  display: flex;
  cursor: unset !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  .slide {
    .image {
      position: relative;
      img {
        width: 100% !important;
        height: auto !important;
        object-fit: cover;
      }
      .icon {
        transition: 0.5s ease;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        text-align: center;
        span {
          svg {
            font-size: 30px;
            color: #fff;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  .image:hover .icon {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.image:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(211, 208, 208, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.image:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Here's the link of **[demo](https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/jackco/)** (kindly see just above the footer section) for your reference.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

For draggle Slider there is a very lightweight JS Carousel package - siema
It is a great, lightweight carousel that is made with JS. There are also other packages built on top of this purely made for React.

In your case, I would offer to try out react-siema.

With it, you can simply use the carousel like that and it will be draggable by default. Plus, no need to load any css.